# calculate value in array of textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a textbox array in my form, where i need to calculate the cost price according to the percentage
when i enter the price and % , cp is calculated with mouseup event

```
sp1(name = price[] class = price)  %(class = perc)  cp1(name = cost[] class = cost)
sp2(name = price[] class = price)  %(class = perc)  cp2(name = cost[] class = cost)
sp3(name = price[] class = price)  %(class = perc)  cp3(name = cost[] class = cost)
sp4(name = price[] class = price)  %(class = perc)  cp4(name = cost[] class = cost)
sp5(name = price[] class = price)  %(class = perc)  cp5(name = cost[] class = cost)
```

here is my jquery code

```
$(function(){
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0];
var taxAmount = document.getElementsByClassName('cost')[0];
var tax = document.getElementsByClassName('perc')[0];

tax.onblur = function() {
    var taxAmount1= parseFloat(price.value) * parseFloat(tax.value) / 100;
    var tt = parseInt(price.value)-parseInt(taxAmount1);
   taxAmount.value=tt;
}   
});
```

but this only calculate for the first textboxes how can i do it for whole textbox array
and i'm using array because i want to submit this form in php.

will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors work perfectly well for an array of matching elements, so if you write,

```
$('.perc').blur( function() {
    ...
} );
```

the event will be handled for all elements of class 'perc'. Now to proceed with the calculation, you would need to access the remaining fields with class 'price' and 'cost', fetch the value with `$theElement.val()` and do your calculation.

The two easiest ways are

1. starting from the element which caused the event, $(this), navigate through your DOM tree and search for the remaining fields. For example, if the input fields for price, taxAmount and tax are siblings, you could use the correpsonding [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) (`$(this).siblings('.cost').val();`). There are other methods to access parent, children, etc.
2. store the index for the three related input fields in a HTML5 data attribute, like `<input ... class="price" data-index="0" />`. That way, you can easily select the other fields with `var index = $(this).data('index'); var price = $('input[data-index="' + index + '"].price').val();`

You should be able to continue with these hints. For more detailled elaboration, please provide the relevant HTML structure.